# How to use activity onBackPressed() and fragment onResume() methods to well synchronize fragments callback?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to use of activity onBackPressed() and fragment onResume() methods call to well synchronize fragments callback ?

I have an activity A with a framelayout F.

By default activity A loads a layout L in the framelayout F.

L contains a button that loads fragment F1.

F1 can load itself with another contain or load F2.

When I press phone Back button, I tried it several times and it was a complete mess. Either the framelayout is empty or the synchronisation misfunction

I am a newbie.

How can I perfectly achieve this by pressing phone Back button ?
Thanks in advance. (Excuse my english)

Fragments call process here : 
https://ibb.co/fhqEJ6

Comment: This question is very broad.  Please post the fragments, indicate what you have tried and what error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use a FragmentTransaction when creating a new fragment from F1, and in that transaction make sure that you call the addToBackStack() method.  Using that process, when you press the Back button from the new fragment, Android will automatically show the previous fragment that launched the new one.

You can review the documentation on fragment transactions at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions.

Comment: Sure I did. I used FragmentTransaction. The problem is the mess I got when I press the Back button. Either the framelayout into I launch the fragment is empty or nothing happens.